# Flask Python Routing is not working after clicking button to direct to another page

Tags: python, mysql, vue.js, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two html pages called ViewRoles.html and Detailspage.html where user can view roles in the former and click a button called "View Details" to direct to Detailspage.html to view the skills associated with it.
I would need the role_id in order to get the skills from the database. My problem now is that the redirection is unsuccessful even though I have append the role_id to the URL after clicking the button "View Details" to pass it over to the server in ViewRole.py.
Could anyone help to guide me?
It gave me this error {
"code": 500,
"message": "An error occurred: 'skill' is undefined"
}
My code:-

#ViewRole.py

```
@app.route('/detailpage', methods=['GET'])
def detail_page():
    # Get the roleId from the query parameter
    role_id = request.args.get('roleId')
    print(role_id)

    # Handle the case where roleId is not provided
    if role_id is None:
        return jsonify(
            {
                "code": 400,
                "message": "Role ID is required."
            }
        ), 400
    try:
        # Replace this with logic to fetch skills based on the role_id from the database
        query = text("SELECT sd.skill_id, sd.skill_name, sd.skill_status FROM skill_details AS sd JOIN role_skills AS rs ON sd.skill_id = rs.skill_id WHERE rs.role_id = :role_id")
        skillsList = db.session.execute(query, {'role_id': role_id})

        skillsListData = []

        for row in skillsList:
            skills_dict = {
                "skill_id": row.skill_id,
                "skill_name": row.skill_name,
                "skill_status": row.skill_status
            }
            skillsListData.append(skills_dict)

        if skillsListData:
            return render_template("DetailPage.html", role_id=role_id, skills=skillsListData)

        return jsonify(
            {
                "code": 404,
                "message": "There are no skills matched yet for this role."
            }
        ), 404

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify(
            {
                "code": 500,
                "message": f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
            }
        ), 500
```

#ViewRoles.html

```
<div id="app">
        <h1>Role Listings</h1>
        <ul v-if="roles.length > 0">
            <li v-for="role in roles" :key="role.role_listing_id">
                <h2>{{ role.role_listing_id}}</h2>
                <h3>{{ role.role_title}}</h3>
                <p>Role ID: {{ role.role_id }}</p>
                <p>Role Description: {{ role.role_listing_desc}}</p>
                <p>Open Date: {{ role.role_listing_open }}</p>
                <p>Close Date: {{ role.role_listing_close }}</p>
                <button @click="navigateToDetailPage(role.role_id)">View Details</button>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <p v-else>No open roles</p>
    </div>

    

    <script>
        const app = Vue.createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    roles: [], 
                };
            },
            methods:{
                 // Method to navigate to the detail page
                navigateToDetailPage(roleId) {

                    const detailPageUrl = `http://localhost:5001/detailpage?roleId=${roleId}`;
                    // Redirect the user to the detail page
                    window.location.href = detailPageUrl;
                },
            },
            mounted() {
                fetch("http://localhost:5001/openRoles")
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log(data)
                        this.roles = data.data.openRoles;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error("Error fetching role listings:", error);
                    });
            }
        });

        app.mount("#app"); 
    </script>
```

#Detailpage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>View Skills</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Skills List</h1>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="skill in skills" :key="skill.skill_id">
                <p>Skill ID: {{ skill.skill_id }}</p>
                <p>Skill Name: {{ skill.skill_name }}</p>
                <p>Skill Status: {{ skill.skill_status }}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        const app = Vue.createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    skills: [], 
                };
            },
            mounted() {
                fetch(`http://localhost:5001/detailpage/${roleId}`) 
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        this.skills = data.data.skills;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error fetching skills:', error);
                    });
            },
        });

        app.mount('#app');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```